# Arch-Linux after system-update no internet connection but connection lan

Tags: arch-linux, ip, ethernet, internet, ping

Yesterday I updated my Arch Linux after 2 Months with `sudo pacman -Syu` and after the reboot I don't get any connection with the Internet neither from Browser nor with Skype, etc.

When I try to ping google.com I get

```
~]# ping google.com
ping: unkown host google.com
```

When I check the ethernet-connection:

```
ip link
1: .....
2: enps2o: ... state UP ...
```

and with ´ip addr´ i also see that I still have my regular IP addres.

After restarting the dhcp-service I got the same IP from the DHCP-server in our university, but still no internet connection. 
So I'll have a look to set up all my ethernet settings new, maybe there's something broken after the update.

After pulling out my ethernet-cable I had for about 2s connecting to the internet, but than it disconnected again

Here is the requested update log, and sorry I did the last update on the 15. of July so its only 2 Weeks away :)

```
[2015-07-15 09:42] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S banshee'
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] transaction started
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed libgdiplus (3.12-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed mono (4.0.2.5-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gtk-sharp-2 (2.12.22-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed mono-addins (1.1-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed dbus-sharp (0.8.1-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed dbus-sharp-glib (0.6.0-1)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gdata-sharp (1.7.0.1-3)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed taglib-sharp (2.1.0.0-2)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gudev-sharp (0.1-3)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gkeyfile-sharp (0.1-3)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gconf-sharp (2.24.2-4)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed mono-zeroconf (0.9.0-4)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed mono-upnp (0.1.2-2)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed gvfs (1.24.1-2)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] installed banshee (2.6.2-7)
[2015-07-15 09:42] [ALPM] transaction completed
[2015-08-04 14:42] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S jdk8-openjdk'
[2015-08-04 14:42] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu'
[2015-08-04 14:42] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2015-08-04 14:42] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] transaction started
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] removed eclipse (4.4.2-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded gcc-libs (5.1.0-5 -> 5.2.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded sqlite (3.8.10.2-1 -> 3.8.11.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded libdbus (1.8.18-1 -> 1.8.20-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded dbus (1.8.18-1 -> 1.8.20-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded libsystemd (221-2 -> 224-1)
[2015-08-04 14:44] [ALPM] upgraded systemd (221-2 -> 224-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded llvm-libs (3.6.1-1 -> 3.6.2-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded mesa (10.6.2-1 -> 10.6.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded mesa-libgl (10.6.2-1 -> 10.6.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1 -> 0.15-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded harfbuzz (0.9.41-1 -> 1.0.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded qt4 (4.8.7-1 -> 4.8.7-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded akonadi (1.13.0-4 -> 1.13.0-6)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gnutls (3.4.2-1 -> 3.4.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] installed libsoxr (0.1.1-3)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libssh (0.7.0-2 -> 0.7.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libx264 (2:144.20150223-1 -> 2:148.20150725-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded ffmpeg (1:2.7.1-1 -> 1:2.7.2-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded exiv2 (0.24-1 -> 0.25-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded strigi (0.7.8-6 -> 0.7.8-7)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libdatrie (0.2.8-1 -> 0.2.9-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libthai (0.1.21-1 -> 0.1.22-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded kfilemetadata4 (4.14.3-1 -> 4.14.3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded mpfr (3.1.3-1 -> 3.1.3.p4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded baloo4-widgets (4.14.3-1 -> 4.14.3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded binutils (2.25-5 -> 2.25.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded cabextract (1.4-3 -> 1.6-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded cairomm (1.10.0-3 -> 1.11.2-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded ceph (0.94.2-1 -> 0.94.2-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded cmake (3.2.3-1 -> 3.3.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded colord (1.2.9-3 -> 1.2.11-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libcups (2.0.3-1 -> 2.0.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded cups (2.0.3-1 -> 2.0.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded device-mapper (2.02.123-1 -> 2.02.125-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded dhcpcd (6.9.0-1 -> 6.9.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded jre7-openjdk-headless (7.u79_2.5.5-1 -> 7.u85_2.6.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded jre7-openjdk (7.u79_2.5.5-1 -> 7.u85_2.6.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded jdk7-openjdk (7.u79_2.5.5-1 -> 7.u85_2.6.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libsecret (0.18.2-1 -> 0.18.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded harfbuzz-icu (0.9.41-1 -> 1.0.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libepoxy (1.2-2 -> 1.3.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gdk-pixbuf2 (2.31.4-1 -> 2.31.5-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gtk-update-icon-cache (3.16.5-1 -> 3.16.6-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gtk3 (3.16.5-1 -> 3.16.6-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libmm-glib (1.4.8-2 -> 1.4.10-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libnm-glib (1.0.2-4 -> 1.0.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] installed webkitgtk (2.4.9-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] installed eclipse-common (4.5.0-3)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] installed eclipse-java (4.5.0-3)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded file (5.23-2 -> 5.24-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded firefox-adblock-plus (2.6.8-1 -> 2.6.9-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded flashplugin (11.2.202.481-1 -> 11.2.202.491-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gcc (5.1.0-5 -> 5.2.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded git (2.4.5-1 -> 2.5.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gst-plugins-ugly (1.4.5-2 -> 1.4.5-3)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gstreamer0.10-ugly (0.10.19-14 -> 0.10.19-15)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gstreamer0.10-ugly-plugins (0.10.19-14 -> 0.10.19-15)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libinput (0.19.0-1 -> 0.21.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded kfilemetadata (5.9.2-1 -> 5.9.2-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded kdeclarative (5.12.0-1 -> 5.12.0-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded gwenview (15.04.3-1 -> 15.04.3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libtool (2.4.6-2 -> 2.4.6-3)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded talloc (2.1.2-1 -> 2.1.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded kdebase-runtime (15.04.3-3 -> 15.04.3-4)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-libldap (2.4.40-1 -> 2.4.41-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-curl (7.42.1-1 -> 7.43.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-gcc-libs (5.1.0-5 -> 5.2.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-gnutls (3.4.2-1 -> 3.4.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-libdbus (1.8.18-1 -> 1.8.20-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-libtiff (4.0.3-3 -> 4.0.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-llvm-libs (3.6.1-1 -> 3.6.2-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-systemd (221-1 -> 224-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-mesa (10.6.2-1 -> 10.6.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-mesa-libgl (10.6.2-1 -> 10.6.3-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lib32-sqlite (3.8.10.2-1 -> 3.8.11.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libgphoto2 (2.5.7-1 -> 2.5.8-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libkexiv2 (15.04.3-1 -> 15.04.3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libkolabxml (1.1.0-2 -> 1.1.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libnice (0.1.10-1 -> 0.1.13-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libteam (1.14-2 -> 1.17-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libunistring (0.9.5-1 -> 0.9.6-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] warning: directory permissions differ on /var/lib/libvirt/qemu/
filesystem: 755  package: 770
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded libvirt (1.2.17-1 -> 1.2.18-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] >>> You may need to run 'rm -rf ~/.libvirt'
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded linux-firmware (20150527.3161bfa-1 -> 20150722.e10097a-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded linux (4.0.7-2 -> 4.1.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] >>> Updating module dependencies. Please wait ...
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] >>> Generating initial ramdisk, using mkinitcpio.  Please wait...
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'default'
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.1.4-1-ARCH
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [autodetect]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux.img
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Building image from preset: /etc/mkinitcpio.d/linux.preset: 'fallback'
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> -k /boot/vmlinuz-linux -c /etc/mkinitcpio.conf -g /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img -S autodetect
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Starting build: 4.1.4-1-ARCH
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [base]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [udev]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [modconf]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [block]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: aic94xx
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> WARNING: Possibly missing firmware for module: wd719x
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [filesystems]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [keyboard]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   -> Running build hook: [fsck]
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Generating module dependencies
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Creating gzip-compressed initcpio image: /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] ==> Image generation successful
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded linux-headers (4.0.7-2 -> 4.1.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:45] [ALPM] upgraded lvm2 (2.02.123-1 -> 2.02.125-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded man-pages (4.00-1 -> 4.01-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded maven (3.3.3-1 -> 3.3.3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded mercurial (3.4.2-1 -> 3.5-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded mplayer (37379-3 -> 37379-4)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded netctl (1.10-2 -> 1.11-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded networkmanager (1.0.2-4 -> 1.0.4-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] warning: directory permissions differ on /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin/
filesystem: 777  package: 755
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded npm (2.13.0-1 -> 2.13.2-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded openjdk7-doc (7.u79_2.5.5-1 -> 7.u85_2.6.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded openjdk7-src (7.u79_2.5.5-1 -> 7.u85_2.6.1-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded openjdk8-doc (8.u45-1 -> 8.u51-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded openjdk8-src (8.u45-1 -> 8.u51-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded openssh (6.9p1-1 -> 6.9p1-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] warning: /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist installed as /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist.pacnew
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded pacman-mirrorlist (20150713-1 -> 20150731-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded pacman (4.2.1-1 -> 4.2.1-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded perl-dbi (1.633-2 -> 1.634-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded perl-uri (1.68-1 -> 1.69-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded perl-http-message (6.08-1 -> 6.10-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded sip (4.16.8-1 -> 4.16.9-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded python2-sip (4.16.8-1 -> 4.16.9-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded qjackctl (0.3.13-1 -> 0.4.0-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded speech-dispatcher (0.8.3-2 -> 0.8.3-5)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] warning: /etc/sudoers installed as /etc/sudoers.pacnew
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded sudo (1.8.13-1 -> 1.8.14.p3-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded systemd-sysvcompat (221-2 -> 224-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-host-modules (4.3.28-2 -> 5.0.0-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] In order to use the new version, reload all virtualbox modules manually.
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox (4.3.28-1 -> 5.0.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-ext-vnc (4.3.28-1 -> 5.0.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-guest-iso (4.3.28-1 -> 5.0.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-guest-modules (4.3.28-2 -> 5.0.0-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded xorg-server-common (1.17.2-2 -> 1.17.2-4)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded xorg-server (1.17.2-2 -> 1.17.2-4)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded virtualbox-guest-utils (4.3.28-1 -> 5.0.0-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded wine (1.7.47-1 -> 1.7.48-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] installed l-smash (2.3.0-2)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded x264 (2:144.20150223-1 -> 2:148.20150725-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] upgraded xf86-video-intel (1:2.99.917+364+gb24e758-1 -> 1:2.99.917+381+g5772556-1)
[2015-08-04 14:46] [ALPM] transaction completed
```

Console-Output:

```
[sebastian@ulbp2681 ~]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 4c:72:b9:4b:08:09 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 141.35.23.78/22 brd 141.35.23.255 scope global enp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::856b:fd54:837f:38d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[sebastian@ulbp2681 ~]$ ip route
default via 141.35.20.1 dev enp2s0  metric 202
141.35.20.0/22 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 141.35.23.78  metric 202
[sebastian@ulbp2681 ~]$ journalctl -b _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service
-- No entries --
```

after I was checking my syslog I fpund that:

```
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 kernel: alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: fatal interrupt 0x400, resetting
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 kernel: alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: carrier lost
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: deleting default route via 141.35.20.1
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: Withdrawing address record for 141.35.23.78 on enp2s0.
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 141.35.23.78.
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: Interface enp2s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: carrier acquired
Aug 06 06:45:23 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: rebinding lease of 141.35.23.78
Aug 06 06:45:25 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: Deleting interface #84 enp2s0, 141.35.23.78#123, interface stats: received=4, sent=36, dropped=0, active_time=713 secs
Aug 06 06:45:25 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: 5.9.159.253 local addr 141.35.23.78 -> <null>
Aug 06 06:45:25 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: 144.76.96.7 local addr 141.35.23.78 -> <null>
Aug 06 06:45:25 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: 129.70.132.35 local addr 141.35.23.78 -> <null>
Aug 06 06:45:25 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: 85.10.246.226 local addr 141.35.23.78 -> <null>
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: leased 141.35.23.78 for 691200 seconds
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp2s0.IPv4 with address 141.35.23.78.
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: adding route to 141.35.20.0/22
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: New relevant interface enp2s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: adding default route via 141.35.20.1
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 avahi-daemon[455]: Registering new address record for 141.35.23.78 on enp2s0.IPv4.
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 NetworkManager[453]: <info>  Policy set 'enp2s0' (enp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Aug 06 06:45:29 ulbp2681 dhcpcd[1226]: enp2s0: removing route to 141.35.20.0/22
Aug 06 06:45:31 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: Listen normally on 85 enp2s0 141.35.23.78:123
Aug 06 06:45:31 ulbp2681 ntpd[491]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Aug 06 06:55:47 ulbp2681 kernel: alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: fatal interrupt 0x400, resetting
Aug 06 06:55:47 ulbp2681 kernel: alx 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: NIC Up: 1 Gbps Full
....
```

SO how could I solve this bug in the kernel?
I tried a rollback to the pivious kernel, but this didn't work eather maybe I did it wrong?

Comment: Check your dns configuration

Comment: How do you manage your network connection? What is in the journal? What was updated? More information is needed...

Comment: I added some Information

Comment: Can you please post the section of `pacman.log` (By default `/var/log/pacman.log`) corresponding to the update procedure from yesterday? I expect this will be a very long file since you hadn't updated in several months. Also post the **last line of the previous update** so that we can tell when it took place (for relevant update informations during that time period).

Comment: I added the log

Comment: The previous visible operation is not an update, but based on the `git` and `linux` version you had before updating, the previous update likely was between June the 30th and July the 4th. What do `ip addr` and `ip route` say?

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in `journalctl -b _SYSTEMD_UNIT=NetworkManager.service` ?

Comment: I updated my question, have a look it it,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26612/discussion-between-sebastian-roher-and-emeric).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug the kernel.

After rollback and downgrade of all updated network packages it works again

this was the command i used:

```
[root@ulbp2681 ~]# cd /var/cache/pacman/pkg
[root@ulbp2681 pkg]# pacman -U linux-4.0.7-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz linux-headers-4.0.7-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz dhcpcd-6.9.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz netctl-1.10-2-any.pkg.tar.xz networkmanager-1.0.2-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz
```

2 things I needed to find the solution:

> 1. journalsctl -b for systemlog after current boot
> 2. pacman-logfiles to see what has been updated